# shortest way to test the match of an empty literal parenthesis sequence

Tags: regex, bash

After a headlock I ask for some help involving bash and regex.
I want to match a sequence of literal empty parenthesis.
They should be opening and closing each-one to each-other as follow :

**to match :** ""  or  "()"  or  "()()()()()()"
**not to match :** "(" or "((()()))" or  "))()))()()"

Here's what I tried. (`$s` contains the input string)

- a substitute solution with `sed`, which barely works (except for `$s="."`)

  ```
  [ `echo $s|sed 's/\(()\)*/./'` = "." ]&&echo true||echo false
  ```
- the desired form with `[[ <arg1> =~ <arg2> ]]`, which is not doing well

  ```
  [[ $s =~ \(()\)* ]]&&echo true||echo false
  ```

There are some spaces missing because my aim is to produce the shortest code as possible (personal challenge).
Can someone help me out, please ? :'(

Comment: I only want `true` or `false` depending on the whole pattern is matching or not. I do not want to obtain `true` with `(((())))`, even if the inner `()` is matching.

Comment: Hmm. That's actually something we can do.

Comment: BTW, inasmuch as this was created as a puzzle rather than a practical problem you've encountered, it actually belongs over on [Puzzles & Code Golf SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). As per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, "practical" is part of StackOverflow's mandate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

re='^([(][)])*$'
is_valid() { [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; }

for test_case in '' '()' "()()()()()()" "(" "((()()))" "))()))()()"; do
  if is_valid "$test_case"; then
    echo "matches: $test_case"
  else
    echo "does not match: $test_case"
  fi
done
```

...for which output follows:

```
matches:
matches: ()
matches: ()()()()()()
does not match: (
does not match: ((()()))
does not match: ))()))()()
```

Comment: Thanks a **lot** !  `[[ $s =~ ^([(][)])*$ ]]&&echo true||echo false` is doing perfect !

Comment: @RémiT., `a && b || c` is **not** the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`, so using it as shorthand is a bad habit to be in. If `a` succeeds but `b` fails, then you can have `c` run even though `a` was true.

Comment: I knew it, I used this trick in order to shorten as much as possible ! :)

Comment: Ahh. I tend to favor correctness over terseness, obviously, but will forego the discussion of why storing the regex in a variable is better practice for backwards compatibility with ancient releases of bash if terseness is more your immediate goal. :)

Comment: I'm glad you raised these essential points. But here the sortest the funniest ! :p

Comment: In fact: `[[ $s == *(\(\)) ]]&&a=true||a=false;echo "$a $s"` is shorter :-P

Comment: @sorontar, *nod*. I don't do code golf, and if this had been tagged as such my filter (configured back before [Puzzles & Code Golf SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) was created to rid us of that crap) would have ensured I didn't see it.

Comment: Charles: Yes, you are correct :-) ... I meant to address @RémiT comment ... ... and make an explicit note that a simple pattern (==) may be better/simpler/faster than a regex (=~).

Comment: (BTW, is my memory mistaken, or do not all versions of bash allow extglobs in pattern matches without the shopt switch set? Might need a `shopt -s extglob` on there to make it work on less-recent interpreters).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not all, AFAIK: Since bash 4.1 [Force extglob on temporarily when parsing the pattern argument to the == and != operators to the [[ command, for compatibility.](ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with regular expressions only. You need [something more powerful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). It is because regular expressions can't count how deep parenthesis are nested.

Comment: This is generally true, but the OP's domain is restricted enough that we can cheat. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is seems like you are looking for zero or more occurrences of `()`

**Regex:** `^(\(\))*$`

Python code:

```
regex = "^(\(\))*$"
search = re.search(regex, "()")
print search.string
```

Output: ()

```
search = re.search(regex, "()()")
print search.string
```

Output: ()()

Comment: Ah, but they want to be sure that `(()())` *doesn't* match, because it's inside an outer set of parens; the goal is to ensure that only non-nested parens are matched.

Comment: yes, in that case length of input can be compared to length of match.

Comment: ...with that extension done, the only remaining issue is that the OP was explicitly asking how to do this *in bash*.

Comment: Yes thank you , updated regex doesn't match to partial strings like  `(()())`  . Now regex looks for whole string for the pattern.